# What debuffs and disables are removed by Legion Commander's "Press The Attack"?

Tags: dota-2

The text of Press The Attack states that it removes "debuffs and disables", but it doesn't seem to work on all of them. Is this a bug, or is there a list of debuffs and disables that aren't affected by Press The Attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press The Attack is a strong dispel. Thus, it removes almost everything. The list of the few spells it does not work on can be found here: http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Dispel

Look under the "Strong Dispels" section.